# Azure Virtual Machine Metrics

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using the Azure Java SDK 
I am trying to get the metrics for a Virtual Machine 
My code is mentioned below

List  metricDefinitions = azure.metricDefinitions().listByResource(virtualMachine.id());

but the list size ,i got is Zero.

Is it a issue with SDK or is my code wrong?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Azure specific code.  I know of no such class or method call in the Oracle JDK.  Sounds like Microsoft extended their own version for Azure.

Comment: It is Microsoft Java SDK to interact with Azure cloud.                                                      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Best to check with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same version SDK. And I can successfully get the metricDefinitions list.

With fiddler, I can also see that actually the following API was invokked:

**`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{rsgName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01`**

And there are 21 objects in the json response, which just matches the available metrics shown in portal. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7dsy.png)

I suggest you have another try to see if you can get the result correctly.